# Combining two (multiple) tables using their table name as new field

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables: *car* and *bike*. I want to join these two tables and use their table name as a field name.

```
car
| id | brand       | 
--------------------
|  1 | mercedes    |     
|  2 | bmw         |    
|  3 | audi        |

bike
| id | brand       | 
--------------------
|  1 | mercedes    |     
|  2 | bmw         |    
|  3 | audi        |
```

The select result I want:

```
| id | vId | brand     | type |
-------------------------------
|  1 |  1  | mercedes  | bike | 
|  2 |  2  | bmw       | bike |
|  3 |  3  | harley    | bike |
|  4 |  1  | mercedes  | car  |  
|  5 |  2  | bmw       | car  | 
|  6 |  3  | audi      | car  |
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **UNION ALL** operator.
UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more queries

```
  set @pos=0;

 select @pos:=@pos+1 as id ,bikecar.vid, bikecar.brand,bikecar.type
 from
 (
  select id as Vid,brand,'CAR' as type from car 
    union all 
  select id as Vid,brand,'Bike' as type  from bike 
 ) bikecar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT id, brand, 'car' AS type FROM car
UNION ALL
SELECT id, brand, 'bike' AS type FROM bike
```

Comment: one additional question @OTARKIKI , in your example i can't use a WHERE or LIKE option. Is there a part i have missed?